# Warning: isInitialValid has been deprecated and will be removed in future versions of Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik, formik-material-ui

*Warning: isInitialValid has been deprecated and will be removed in future versions of Formik. Please use initialErrors or validateOnMount instead.*

I didn't find validateOnMount in formik ?

[image]

```
 const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues,
    isInitialValid:false,
    validationSchema ,
    onSubmit: (values, errors) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
       
    },
  });
```

I tried to use ***validateOnMount*** instead of isInitialValid:false but it has error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `validateOnMount`? I had the same issue and got it solved by just adding this.

Comment: You mean validateOnMount ?

Comment: oh there is a simple mistake , I got it it should be validateOnMount : true

Answer (score 0):

Please Add `validateOnMount={true}` this would solve your problem